# Rename ClassNames with React Prod Build

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, uglifyjs

How an I use webpack to uglify css classNames on prod builds?!

For example, say I have the following css className used throughout my code.

```
.class_name{}
```

On prod build, I want to uglify and minify the css className to

```
.a4{}
```

I have looked at css-modules but it is too late to go that route as it would mean I have to go through each component and re-write all my components. My ideal solution would be to modify the webpack.config.prod so it uglifies or renames css classes on prod builds only. Please advice!

Comment: You end up finding a solution?